# Scala case class with cached hashCode

Tags: scala

I was under the impression that the hashCode of a Scala case class was solely determined by its fields. Consequently, I thought that caching a hashCode was safe for immutable case classes.

Seems like I am wrong:

```
case class Foo(s: String) {
  override val hashCode: Int = super.hashCode()
}

val f1 = Foo("foo")
val f2 = Foo("foo")

println(f1.hashCode == f2.hashCode) // FALSE
```

Could anyone explain what's going on here, please?

**Addendum** – Just for comparison:

```
case class Bar(s: String)

val b1 = Bar("bar")
val b2 = Bar("bar")

println(b1.hashCode == b2.hashCode) // TRUE
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure about the value of this, but you can inline the implementation of `ScalaRuntime._hashCode`:

```
case class Foo(s: String) {
  override val hashCode: Int = scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.productHash(this)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution: Same behavior as if not overridden (i.e. hash solely based on fields), yet memoized, with an implementation based on public API – thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by "cached hasCode", but ...
You've override `hashCode` with custom solution that built from `Object`, that is why you're getting `false`. Remove this override and you'll get expected value.

Comment: I wanted to memoize the hashCode of an immutable case class. But you're spot on, I should have used `override def hashCode(): Int = ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this)` instead of `super.hashCode()`! This is not public API though... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Rumoku's answer seems to get at what's really going on here.  When you declare `case class Foo` it compiles into this: `case class Foo extends AnyRef with Product with Serializable` (see `scalac`'s `-Xprint:typer` option).  In addition, an implementation of `hashCode` is also generated as follows: `override def hashCode: Int = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this)`.  When you override `hashCode` yourself however, this implementation is not generated.  The key is that neither `Product` nor `Serializable` implement `hashCode` so the implementation that you're picking up when you call `super.hashCode` is the default implementation from `AnyRef`/`Any`/`Object`.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` of the case class instance is solely dependent on its fields not `hashCode`

Comment: Well, it is the case if `hashCode` is not overridden – see my addendum